# If you roll eight 12-sided dice at one time, what is the chance you get five of any one number?

Tags: probability

If you roll eight 12-sided dice at one time, what is the chance that you get five of ANY one number? What is the chance that you get five of a SPECIFIC number, say, number 2?

Comment: I suggest you consider the second question first. Do you know what a Bernoulli trial is? (or a binomial experiment)

Comment: Considering the second question first, suppose my specific number is `2`. In order for your event to occur, must I get _exactly_ five `2`'s (as in `22232237`) or may I get _at least_ five `2`'s (as in `22222225` or `42221222`)? Of course, the second is more likely than the first.

Comment: you may get at least five 2's... and no I do not know what a benoulli trial is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your second question: the probability of getting *exactly* five 2s out of eight 12-sided dice is $\frac{8!}{5! \times 3!} (\frac{1}{12})^5 (\frac{11}{12})^3$

For each 12-sided die, the probability of getting a 2 is 1/12, and of getting something else than a 2 is 11/12. The $\frac{8!}{5! \times 3!}$ term represents the choice of which 5 dice will give a 2.

Moving back to the first question: to get the probability of getting *exactly* five of any one number, we multiply this by the number of possible numbers, here 12, so: $12 \times \frac{8!}{5! \times 3!} (\frac{1}{12})^5 (\frac{11}{12})^3$

Comment: Don't give full answers to obvious homework questions please.

Comment: Could you indicate more clearly which of the two questions you are answering?

Comment: Ha, this is not a homework question. It's a fantasy football question. A guy in our league has somehow won five times in the first eight years, which seems unfathomable.